# React native switch is not clickable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

here is the code

```
const toggleSwitch = () => {
  console.log("clicked");
  props.updateAvailability(!isEnabled);
  setIsEnabled(!isEnabled);
};
```

**Render part**

```
<View
  style={{
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  }}
>
  <Text style={styles.name}>{props.name}</Text>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Switch
      trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: Colors.borderColor }}
      thumbColor={isEnabled ? Colors.green : "#f4f3f4"}
      ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
      onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
      value={isEnabled}
    />
  </View>
</View>;
```

style part

```
name: {
  fontSize: 18,
  fontWeight: "700",
  color: Colors.black1,
  marginRight: 40,
},
```

if the **props.name** have bigger length then the switch is not working

[image: sample image]

in the picture last switch is not working because the length of the **props.name**

Answer (score 0):

You can use width instead of flex and it will work.

```
<View
style={{
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    width:"100%"// add this
  }}
>
  <Text style={styles.name}>{props.name}</Text>
  <View style={{ width:"30%" // add this and remove flex:1 }}>
    <Switch
      trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: Colors.borderColor }}
      thumbColor={isEnabled ? Colors.green : "#f4f3f4"}
      ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
      onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
      value={isEnabled}
    />
  </View>
</View>;


name: {
 fontSize: 18,
  fontWeight: "700",
  color: Colors.black1,
  marginRight: 40,
  width:"60%"// add this
},
```